# Tensorflow infinity mask breaks gradient

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, gradient, mask, infinity

I'm trying to do softmax over selected indices, using infinity mask to silent out the unwanted ones. However, the gradient of those unwanted entires become `nan` as opposed to `0`.

The reason I didn't use boolean mask is that the mask indices are different in my batch, which can't end up with a nice matrix form. If there's workaround here I'll be more than happy to adopt.

The code I tested the infinity mask is

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [5])
inf_mask = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [5])

b = tf.multiply(a, inf_mask)
sf = tf.nn.softmax(b)

loss = (sf[2] - 0)
grad = tf.gradients(loss, a)

sess = tf.Session()

a_np = np.ones([5])
np_mask = np.ones([5]) * 4
np_mask[1] = -np.inf

print sess.run([sf, grad], feed_dict={
    a: a_np,
    inf_mask: np_mask
})

sess.close()
```

The output is

```
[array([ 0.25,  0.  ,  0.25,  0.25,  0.25], dtype=float32), [array([-0.25,   nan,  0.75, -0.25, -0.25], dtype=float32)]]
```

The mask is working but the gradient has a `nan`, which should have been `0` I think.

Comment: As mentioned in the [github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11756#issuecomment-396755424), the solution is to define the mask to consist of zeros and `np.inf` and to subtract it, instead of multiplying it.